# UML-Designer: Hide labels on associations

Tags: uml-designer

My first post on stackoverflow, 'hope I do it the right way :-)

I want to create a new entity-relationship-model of our new project.
After a little bit of search I found UMLDesigner. Installation was easy and create this first classes also.
But when I "paint" associations, I got "hundreds" of labels around them.
Have a look into the documentation, I found a way to hide labels, but ...
But
a) I could not select association lables in bulk. The filter works only of the caption of a object and not of the typ (e.g. association vs. class).
Is there a way to only select "associations"?
b) If I hide "a" label of the association, all labels are hidden. What I wanted was to hide only the "end"/role"-labels, but not the name of the association itself
c) Is there a global way to hide/show labels or have I always select a new created object and then hide things?

Question over question, maybe someone can answer them :-)
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks great to see you managed to install it.
Sorry, no it exists no bulk actions on hide you should select one by one the element or decide to hide all.